# iPhone Rich Text Control

Tags: iphone, hyperlink, formatted-text

I am about to build an iPhone screen where I need to display formatted text, a link that will kick off a browser, and an email address link that will kick off the mail client.

Which widget do I use for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do the very thing you are looking to do in my app with a [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). I'm not sure what kind of rich text format you were planning on using, but `UIWebView` takes HTML. There are a couple delegates you'll need to cover for the view to launch URLs in Safari Mobile (otherwise they'll appear directly in your `UIWebView`, which might not be what you want.) Email links should launch the iPhone's Mail app.